# How to conditionally instantiate a named Unity registration type

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, prism

I have looked around on StackOverflow for a solution to my problem.  Though I don't think this is a unique problem, I haven't been able to find a good solution.

In my WPF application, in my viewmodels, I need to call some services to return some data.  These services get injected with UnitOfWork which in turn gets injected with the DbContext.  This dbcontext that get injected into the UnitOfWork should differ based on some criteria.

I am having trouble doing the IoC container registrations the right way and injecting the right DbContext at runtime.  So, if someone can please fill in the blanks (in the unity registrations as well as it's usage).  I have some inline comments in the following code where I am in trouble and need help.  Thanks.

If someone can replace my Registration code the right way and also educate me how to use it in my WPF ViewModel class, that would be truly great!  Thanks.

One final note: If you find coding errors in this code, please don't start wondering how does this even compile? The code here is not my real code.  To simplify things, I just wrote them up.  But it does resemble very closely to my real app code.

```
public interface IDBContext{}
public interface IUnitOfWork{}
public interface ISomeEntityService{}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{ T GetSingle( Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate ); }

public class DBContext1 : IDBContext
{
    public DBContext1(connString) : base(connString){}
}

public class DBContext2 : IDBContext
{
    public DBContext2(connString) : base(connString){}
}


public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IDBContext context;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbSet;

    public Repository(IDBContext ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
        dbSet = ((DbContext)context).Set<T>();
    }

    public T GetSingle( Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate )
    {
        return ((DbContext)context).Set<T>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    IDBContext ctx;
    private Dictionary<string, dynamic> repositories;

    public UnitOfWork(IDBContext context)
    {
        ctx = context;
    }

    public IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (repositories == null)
            repositories = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

        var type = nameof(T);
        if (repositories.ContainsKey(type))
            return (IRepository<T>)repositories[type];

        var repositoryType = typeof(Repository<>);
        repositories.Add(type, Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(T)), ctx));
        return repositories[type];
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class MyUnityBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<IDBContext, DBContext1>("Context1");
        Container.RegisterType<IDBContext, DBContext2>("Context2");
        Container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
        Container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    }
}

public class SomeEntityService : ISomeEntityService
{
    private IUnitOfWork uow;

    public ConsumerService( IUnitOfWork _uow )
    { uow = _uow; }

    public SomeEntity GetSomeData( int id )
    {
        return uow.Repository<SomeEntity>().GetSingle( x => x.Id == id);
    }
}

public class SomeViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly ISomeEntityService someService;
    public SomeViewModel( ISomeEntityService _someService)
    {
        // when I call someService, I want to make sure it is using either
        // DBContext1 or DBContext2 based on some condition I can set here.
        // This is where I am totally stuck.
        someService = _someService;
    }

    // get the repository instance with an id of 1000
    someService.GetSomeData( 1000 );
}

/*
    I could do something like this.  But I am afraid, I am violating 
    two of the best practices recommendations.
    1. I am creating a dependency to my IoC Container here.
    2. I am using the container as a Service Locator
*/
public class SomeViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly ISomeEntityService someService;
    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        var container = SomeHowGetTheContainer();
        /*
            1. Call Container.Resolve<IDBContext>(with the required context);
            2. Use the retrieved context to inject into the UnitOfWork
            3. Use the retrieved UnitOfWork to inject into the service

            But that would be like throwing everything about best practices to the wind!
        */
        someService = container.Resolve<ISomeEntityService>( /*do some magic here to get the right context*/) 
    }

    // get the repository instance with an id of 1000
    someService.GetSomeData( 1000 );
}
```

Comment: I'd hide the call to the container in an abstract factory implementation. It's okay for factories to depend on the container.

Comment: @Haukinger : can you please include some code to show me how, in my scenario?  That would help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a factory like this that resolves your `ISomeEntityService`:

```
public MySomeEntityServiceFactory
{
    public MySomeEntityServiceFactory( IUnityContainer container )
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public ISomeEntityService CreateSomeEntityService( bool condition )
    {
        return _container.Resolve<ISomeEntityService>( condition ? "VariantA" : "VariantB" );
    }

    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
}
```

and add two named bindings like:

```
_container.RegisterType<ISomeEntityService, SomeEntityService>( "VariantA", new InjectionConstructor( new ResolvedParameter<IDBContext>( "VariantA" ) ) );
_container.RegisterType<ISomeEntityService, SomeEntityService>( "VariantB", new InjectionConstructor( new ResolvedParameter<IDBContext>( "VariantB" ) ) );
```

For `IUnitOfWork`, you can add a similar factory that resolves the unit of work, and call it in `SomeEntityService`'s constructor passing in the `IDBContext`...

Those factories are additional dependencies themselves, btw...

Comment: Thanks!  Let me see if I get it.  My **ViewModel** will receive a constructor parameter ISomeEntityServiceFactory instead of ISomeService.  In the ViewModel constructor, I will then call `factory.CreateService` method passing appropriate parameter to obtain the correct service.  Same way, UnitOfWork will recieve a `IContextFactory` as a parameter and that factory will create the appropriate DbContext.  Am I correct?  Let me give it a shot and will let you know the result ASAP.  Thanks again.

Comment: This is not a factory, but a ServiceLocator pattern, which is considered of some as an anti-pattern. See [Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/01/PatternRecognitionAbstractFactoryorServiceLocator/)'s article on the subject.

Comment: A factory in it self is kind of a service locator, one could argue. Yet a dependency on a factory is a clear statement that one depends on the product, whereas a dependency on a service locator just hides dependencies. Sure, depending on the container isn't nice, but it's ok for factories. What else should they use to create products - `new`? `Activator.CreateInstance`? Both are clearly inferior to the container, and the factory won't use the container to hide anything, because the dependcies of the product itself are clearly stated in the products constructor.

Comment: The service locator anti pattern means that you use the container / static access to the container to create _any_ service, _anywhere_. Using the container in the `CreateProduct` method of a factory to create the _product_ is completely fine.

Comment: @Haukinger Thanks Haukinger!  I combined suggestions and ideas from multiple members at this forum and came up with a solution.  It is not a purist DI approach (I am still violating the Hollywood principle - as Seemann would put it), but for lack of a better solution, this works for me.  I am marking your answer as accepted.  Thanks again.